# get Ansible MASTER Machine (where ansible is installed and running) hostname

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Is there a special variable where **ansible master machine hostname** is stored (not hosts where action are running : `ansible_host` `inventory_hostname` ) ?

I want to get my local **hostname** while running a playbook against hosts.

for example i have installed my ansible on : `machine1` and i'm running it against `machine_dev` , how to get `machine1` in a special variable without a localhost hostname shell command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname is stored in the fact `ansible_hostname`. You need to gather facts for this.

All gathered hosts facts are available through the `hostvars` hashmap

If you gather facts for localhost in your very first play, the local hostname will be available anywhere else in `hostvars.localhost.ansible_hostname`

Here is a quick demo of how you can use this.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: show localhost hostname for each current host in the play loop
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars.localhost.ansible_hostname }}"
```

Comment: Merci! so if i understand well, when i execute a play on a host and get it facts , Ansible will always keep the hostvars of that group and i can access them by using : hostvars.MY_HOST_XXX.ansible_hostname , for example where MY_HOST is the host i have execute a task on before  ?

Comment: `hostvars.anyhost` contains all the variables  available for that specific host, including gathered facts if you previously gathered them. Note that, as with other hashmaps, you can use the array notation which can come handy for hostnames containing dots, e.g `hostvars['myhost.localdomain.com']`

Comment: Merci beaucoup !